# Twol form buttons on same line while one is inside a table

Tags: html, html-table, form-submit

I have a form with a submit button in a table to align the inputs such as

```
 Chapter title: [____Input Field____]
 _____________________________________  
| Textarea to be filled               |
|                                     |
| Multiple lines                      |
|_____________________________________| 
[Set]
```

I used `<form ...> <table><tr><td> ...` to align the inputs in different rows.

Now I wanted to add another button which is irrelevant to this form to the right side of Set button.  Let's call it "Reset" button.  so I added another `<form>...` right next to the existing elements.  But the new button is on next row.  I already have a table inside the first form so I couldn't use table and forms can't be nested either.  How do I achieve the goal?

```
 Chapter title: [____Input Field____]
 _____________________________________  
| Textarea to be filled               |
|                                     |
| Multiple lines                      |
|_____________________________________| 
[Set]                 [Reset](desired)  
[Reset](result)
```

### Update : Code

http://jsfiddle.net/o71L6pav/1/

Comment: Please post your html and css.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **float:right** to achieve this.
I don't see your code but you should do something like this:

```
<td> <button class="set" style="float:left"><button class="reset" style="float:right"><div style="clear:both"></div></td>
```